# Method render does not exist laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-paginate

```
$page = Question::paginate(10);
dd($page);
```

Here the pagination working very well but when i use pagination with other models relations then its produce the paginate result but pagination links not appear because its produce error

```
 $questions = Course::with(['questions' => function($query){
                $query->paginate(10);
            },'questions.subjects','questions.years'])
            ->where("status",1)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($course) {
                $query->orWhere('course', '=', $course)
                    ->orWhere('slug', '=', $course);
            })->get();
```

ERROR :

```
 BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
    Method render does not exist.
```

What is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Paginate should be used at the end of a query, and not in relations:

```
$questions = Course::with(['questions','questions.subjects','questions.years'])
        ->where("status",1)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($course) {
            $query->orWhere('course', '=', $course)
                ->orWhere('slug', '=', $course);
        })->paginate(10);
```

Since you are not paginating the main result set, you get the `Method render does not exist` error.

Comment: Thanks but I want pagination in question class not on course, So what i do for pagination.